# Widening and Narrowing of Primitive Types question

Tags: java

I am a first year computer science student. We just starded learning java.
Our prof told us about the widening, but i did not understand something and maybe you can help me.
When you do the following operation (double*int) + (char /-short ) – (float * byte) the answer will be double. But, the teacher also told us that the answer just for (char /-short ) will be float. Why float?

Thanks!

Comment: "the answer just for (char /-short ) will be float" it won't.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is wrong.  The result will be of type `int`.

The exact rules are outlined in the [Java Language Specification section 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), which indicates that both operands of the division will be widened to type `int` before the division takes place, so the result will be an `int`.